# Separate curve below fitting parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, scikit-learn, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit my curve in python.

For simple example I am able to fit.

But, I want to separate a curve with different color or shape below fitting parameter value.

```
#This is my x  and y array

from numpy import sqrt
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from matplotlib import pyplot
import numpy as np
import csv


x = [2, 1.95, 1.9, 1.85, 1.8, 1.75, 1.7, 1.65, 1.6, 1.55, 1.5, 1.45, 1.4, 1.35
 1.3, 1.25, 1.2, 1.15, 1.1, 1.05, 1.01]
y = [1, 1, 1, 1, 0.99, 0.938, 0.9, 0.857, 0.762, 0.686, 0.59, 0.529, 0.509, 0.47, 0.462, 0.452, 0.452, 0.452, 0.457, 0.43,0.424]


print(len(x))
print(len(y))

def func(x, m, n):
    return  1 - 1/2 * np.exp(-(x - m)/(n))


params, covs = curve_fit(func, x, y)
 
print("params: ", params)
print("covariance: ", covs) 

for idx, value in enumerate(x):
    params, _ = curve_fit(func, x, y)
    m, n = params[0], params[1]
    if value >= m:
        yfit1 =  1 - 1/2 * np.exp(-(x - m)/(n))
    else:
        #params, _ = curve_fit(func, x, y)
        #r_t, n = params[0], params[1]
        yfit2 =  1 - 1/2 * np.exp(-(x - m)/(n))
    print(value)
    
plt.plot(x, y, 'bo', linestyle ='solid', marker=">", label="original")
plt.plot(x, yfit1,label="m >= %.3f"%m)
plt.plot(x, yfit2,'ko', marker='>', label="x < m")
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend(loc='best', fancybox=True, shadow=True)
plt.grid(False)
plt.show()
```

Output

```
params:  [1.19707919 0.52674861]

# So this gives 1.197 for m.
```

[image]

When I see my x array I have few values less than the value of m (m=1.197 from params).

So I want to plot them differently(color or size) so that I could have two different style curve with all x bigger than m and remaining x less than m in the same plot.

I tried to give loop by creating two equation but I couldn't get any difference. It seems same graph is plotted over fitted line.

Can I get some help?
Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if-else isn't really working right now as you're doing the same whether the if condition is true or false.

If you're interested in plotting with different styles over different x intervals, here's one way of doing it (you'll just have to replace the final plot section of your code):

```
# Arrays offer an easier indexing compared to lists
x = np.array(x)
y = np.array(y) 

plt.plot(x, y, 'bo', linestyle ='solid', marker=">", label="original")
# Notice the different subsets of the arrays that are being plotted (x<=m and x>m) and tweak these as you like
plt.plot(x[x<=m], yfit1[x<=m],label="m >= %.3f"%m)
plt.plot(x[x>m], yfit1[x>m], 'r:', label="m >= %.3f"%m) 
plt.plot(x, yfit2,'ko', marker='>', label="x < m")
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend(loc='best', fancybox=True, shadow=True)
plt.grid(False)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, you are right, if and else does nothing.I am trying to fix it. Right now your idea works for me. Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi Prahken and Dharman, By chance is it possible to modify a curve which is less than the value of m? Actually, I want to show a line around 0.5 (in y axis) for m less than m and fitting curve (for m greater than x)  starts after that 0.5.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you just need to evaluate your fitted function over x>m and create constant values (or whatever you mean with "show a line") for x<m. You can plot this separately with a different style or combine them together in a new array (yfit_updated).